# Uneven spacing after applying color

Tags: spacing, color

In my document, I need some brackets should highlight in color, for that, I've tried the below code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\begin{document}

\definecolor{bracketcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,1,0}%red
\newcommand{\colorbkt}[1]{\color{bracketcolor}#1\color{black}}%


\[
\left\lvert
p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right\rvert^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left\lvert} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right\rvert}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left( p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right)^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left(} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right)}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left[ p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right]^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left[} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right]}^{-1}
\]


\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

It works, but some additional space coming after the closing brackets, please refer the highlighted screenshot, kindly suggest how I fixed?

Comment: \! closes small space gaps.  Try [p-pc]\!$^{-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use \mathcolor:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\begin{document}

\definecolor{bracketcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,1,0}%red

\newcommand{\colorbkt}[1]{\color{bracketcolor}#1\color{black}}%



\[
\left\lvert
p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right\rvert^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left\lvert} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right\rvert}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left( p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right)^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left(} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right)}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left[ p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right]^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left[} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right]}^{-1}
\]

\renewcommand{\colorbkt}[1]{\mathcolor{bracketcolor}{#1}}% with \mathcolor it works

\[
\left\lvert
p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right\rvert^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left\lvert} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right\rvert}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left( p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right)^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left(} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right)}^{-1}
\]

\[
\left[ p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\right]^{-1}\quad\colorbkt{\left[} p-p_{\mathcal{C}}\colorbkt{\right]}^{-1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I never heard about `mathcolor`. Nice to know.

Comment: It's working fine, sorry for the late confirmation, I too first time I heard about `\mathcolor`